# How to fix buffering issues

Tags: video-streaming

When I try to play a video on a website such as daily motion it automatically buffers two seconds in. I have tried this will multiple websites such as watchop.com and they all seem to buffer every two seconds. On YouTube however the video loads but I can see it doesn't buffer as fast as Windows 8 which is really frustrating because I watch a lot of videos on other third party websites. By the way when I run iwconfig it says I have a bit rate of 72.2 Mb/s.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your "internet" bandwidth 72Mbps?

   - or -
2. Is your internal LAN segment (or wireless segment) giving you 72Mps?

If your house is typical then there would be a DSL/CableModem feeding a local wifi router.

What does [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net) show you for internet speed.